# How to create .cs class for database entity in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am completely new in MVC. I want to create one sample application from which I can do insert,update and delete in one page and view all records in other page. For that I tried to create .cs class for userMST table. As we do in normal application, a class file should have private fields, getter and setter methods to set the fields, insert/update/delete/select methods. But when I tried to define private properties I saw that .net is not allowing me to define private properties not I can set string as the type of the property.

I can not actually understand how the application is created. I did some googling but examples are given which do all the operation from wizard and uses the in-built databse.
Please explain me how to start with MVC and how can I build sample application??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just starting out I would highly recommend you checkout the following tutorials:

- Any blog / book / e-book about the nerd dinner project: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/
- The sample tutorials on the mvc website: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

And after doing that buy a book or two:

- [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234040)
- [Professional ASP.NET MVC 3 (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118076583)